# PyPDF2 return blank page when trying to extract first page

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I have got an issue with the creation of PDF.

First I open the source pdf as a PdfFileReader and get the first page, after that, I add the first page to the pagelist of the output file (PDFFileWriter).

But when I go to check the outputfile it contains only a blank page, here is my code:

```
with open('pdf/'+articolo['itemfilename'], 'rb') as infile:
        reader = PdfFileReader(infile)
        writer = PdfFileWriter() #writer.addPage(reader.getPage(i))
        if articolo['copertina'] == 1:    #this is just a check it works I verified
            writer.addPage(reader.getPage(0))
with open('extracted/'+articolo['itemfilename'], 'wb') as outfile:
    writer.write(outfile)
```

I've already checked with the debugger that the program joins every row of the code, so everything should be fine.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: `particular PDF` so when u run the same code to different PDF it works fine ?

Comment: I'm sorry looks like it doesn't work with another pdf I tested.

Comment: I tried indenting the last two lines of my code inside the first indent block and now it works

Comment: Great!! Problem Solved!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this part of the code:

```
with open('extracted/'+articolo['itemfilename'], 'wb') as outfile:
    writer.write(outfile)
```

Should be indented inside the first indent block like this:

```
with open('pdf/'+articolo['itemfilename'], 'rb') as infile:
    reader = PdfFileReader(infile)
    writer = PdfFileWriter() #writer.addPage(reader.getPage(i))
    if articolo['copertina'] == 1:    #this is just a check it works I verified
        writer.addPage(reader.getPage(0))
    with open('extracted/'+articolo['itemfilename'], 'wb') as outfile:
        writer.write(outfile)
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Looks like the page objects added to the writer contain references to data in the reader, rather than copies, so when the reader is closed the writer loses access to the source data?